# What's the difference in FFMPEG between using -c:v libx264, -c:v copy and -vcodec copy?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-conversion, codec

I'm trying to record video and audio from an IP Camera streaming in H.264.

I found these different options:

```
-i "camera_url"  -c:v libx264 -acodec copy "out.mp4"
-i "camera_url"  -c:v copy -acodec copy "out.mp4"
-i "camera_url"  -vcodec copy -acodec copy "out.mp4"
```

Could anybody tell me what's the difference between those 3 types of recordings?
As far as I understand the last one doesn't do any transcoding so whatever comes from the camera is stored in the file. What about the other 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-codec` option sets the choice of encoder. This can either be the name of an encoder or `copy`. The latter avoids transcoding and copies the packets from input to output. `-c` is a short form for `-codec`. Both of these can accept [stream specifiers](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-specifiers-1), like `-c:v:2` or `-codec:a`. The former will set the encoder for the 3rd video stream in the output and the latter will set the encoder for all audio streams.

`vcodec` and `acodec` are aliases for `-c:v` and `-c:a` but do not accept stream specifiers.